# Accessing the immediately previous result at the Sqlite3 and Psql prompts

Tags: sqlite, postgresql

Some interactive shells have a built-in variable that always points to the results of the previous command (for example in the python3 shell this variable is "_").

Does any such variable exist in the Sqlite3 and Psql prompts?

Comment: No they don't have such a thing nor they have a support for variables at all (unlike Oracle's SQL*Plus that has [bind variables](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/use_vars.html)). See e.g. [How to bind a SQL query return value to a psql variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11654244)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`psql` doesn't, and it's not really a typical way to work with relational data. If you want to retain the result from a previous query, put it in a temporary table.

Do you mean that you want to be able to:

```
SELECT count(somecol), avg(someothercol) FROM _;
```

... for example? ie you want to be able to use your "last result" set and perform further processing on it?

If so, it's usually best to:

- Put the results into a temporary table using [`SELECT INTO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-selectinto.html). This works for pretty much anything, including ordinary `SELECT`, `DELETE ... RETURNING`, `INSERT ... RETURNING`, `UPDATE ... RETURNING`, etc. Then process the temporary table as desired.
- Create a [temporary view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createview.html) of the result. This will of course only work for `SELECT`. `CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW` makes a view that only exists for your session.
- Use readline. Just press the up arrow to get to your previous command, edit as desired, re-run.
- Use the `\e` psql command to open the last command in an external editor (specified with the env var `EDITOR`) where you can modify it more easily.

SQLite won't have a `\e` command and I don't think it has DML commands that can return result sets (`... RETURNING` commands). Otherwise most of that should apply there too.

Comment: yes, this was exactly my question, and [in my case] creating a temporary view was is better then what I was originally asking for, thanks.